# Using other JS libraries with Sencha touch

Tags: mobile, extjs, dojo, sencha-touch

I am looking at sencha touch framework as an option for developing a mobile website.One question I have now is regarding whether we can use components in other javascript libraries like dojo into our sencha touch application.My understanding is that it is not possible to do so.But I would like to get some expert opinion on this.Appreciate if anyone could help me in this matter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't experimented with it but I do doubt that it would look good if you mix Dojo widgets with ST widgets. It may work but it might not look acceptable or function. Sencha Touch is a full-fledged application framework, not just a collection of widgets that you can plug in like some other libraries. You can however extend their widgets and make your own plugins to achieve the look&feel or functionality you desire.

Comment: Seconded. Keeping the codebase as small as possible is a huge factor with mobile development, where CPU/Memory/HardwareAcceleration are as important as they were for regular web-development years ago. Touch and Dojo are both large libraries that solve similar problems. Pick one and stick with it, both are built to be extensible and capable of solving anything you can think of.